# How to get sdcard path in android using ionic framework and phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i am doing a mobile app project using phonegap and ionic framework, now i want to get all the file directory in my sd card and display it in my phone, how should I do it? I know phonegap got API for file, however after i type in these codes, i alert the file location, it gave me that file:///data/data/XXXXX, it was the root file location, i cant access to it, how should i do to get my external sdcard file path?

```js
(function(){
 window.appRootDirName = "test";
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {

  alert("device is ready");
  window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
 }

 function fail() {
  alert("failed to get filesystem");
 }

 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
  alert("filesystem got");
  fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
   create : true,
   exclusive : false
  }, dirReady, fail);
 }

 function dirReady(entry) {
  window.appRootDir = entry;
  alert(window.appRootDir);
  alert(JSON.stringify(window.appRootDir));
  entry.getFile("lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true}, gotFile);
 }
 function gotFile(fileEntry) {
      // Do something with fileEntry here
      alert('success');
  }
})();
```

Comment: in android you can get it via this code  File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
try get something similar

Comment: May i know that how can i use this in javascript? cause i type this code in my controller, it tells me that Environment is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Oh i finally figure out how to use  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); in phonegap, there is a cordova file plugin, you can just install the plugin and use this code to get your external directory. 
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory